# How many solutions does this equation have in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

How many solutions are in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ of this equation:
$x+y+z=6$.
I was thinking to solve with method of circles and lines i don't know if it's a good idea.

Comment: Is `Z0` supposed to denote the non-negative integers? In which case yes an approach using stars and bars (or circles and lines) should work.

Comment: Z0 is supposed all elements of Z and 0 too

Comment: sorry you were right they are non-negative elements of Z

Comment: Circles and lines (often referred to as "stars and bars", though maybe this is USA-centric?) is a good idea. A linear arrangement of $6$ circles and $2$ lines is equivalent to a solution of your equation; the $2$ lines divide the circles into $3$ groups, corresponding to the values of the three variables. How many ways are their to arrange $6$ identical circles and $2$ identical lines in a row?

Comment: maybe 8!/6!x2! is equal to 28 if im not wrong

Comment: @MadeInKosovo: Yes, $\binom82$ is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circles and lines (often referred to as "stars and bars", though maybe this is USA-centric?) is a good idea. A linear arrangement of $6$
 circles and $2$
 lines is equivalent to a solution of your equation; the $2$
 lines divide the circles into $3$
 groups, corresponding to the values of the three variables. How many ways are there to arrange $6$
 identical circles and $2$
 identical lines in a row?

As you said in the comments, there are $\frac{8!}{6!\cdot 2!}$ ways, as there woul be $8!$ ways to arrange $8$ objects, but we divide by $6!$ since the $6$ circles are identical, and divide by $2!$ since the $2$ lines are identical.

Comment: Posting an answer so people can see this problem has been answered.

Comment: thank you so much!